# jenkins vs eclipse-junit: no tests found in

Tags: eclipse, jenkins, ant, junit

I ran a few thousand JUnit tests in Jenkins. Some tests fail with a No tests found in ....Test. I noticed that these tests are problematic because they combine the JUnit3 and the JUnit4 approach. To be more specific these tests:

- extend MyTestCase which extends TestCase (JUnit3)
- the test methods' names don't end in ...test. They have the @Test annotation instead. (JUnit4)

The thing is that when I run these tests in Eclipse I don't get the same error. The tests run normally and they either pass or fail. So my question is this:
How is it possible that Jenkins cannot find the tests whereas Eclipse can? Can I configure Jenkins somehow, in order to run these tests?

Comment: How is your build scripted? Maven? Gradle? Ant? Something else?

Comment: The script that I run via Jenkins is an Ant script. In Eclipse I ran the "problematic" ...Test.java files separately(right click --> Run As --> JUnit Test).

Comment: It would probably help to show the Ant script.

Comment: Jenkins of its' own does not find anything, it is the build tool (Ant, Maven, etc.) that does this. As you are using Ant the problem lies there.

Comment: @cheffe You are right, totally wrong expression, it's not a Jenkins thing!

Answer (score 0):

The tests run in Eclipse with a JUnit4 runner thanks to a @RunWith() annotation. However, ant seems to ignore the annotations and execute the tests as JUnit3 tests because they extend TestCase. 
I managed to solve this based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7796295/running-junit-through-ant-does-not-seem-to-use-custom-class-runner/7812246#7812246) post from @AlexanderMiles. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I still have a problem executing a few tests with Ant though... These tests extend TestCase(JUnit3) and use JUnit4 annotations. The difference is that they are executed with the SpringJUnit4ClassRunner. Eclipse executes them thanks to @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class). Ant does not recognise the annotations ,like in the other case. I do not know if there is a way to force Ant to run these tests with SpringJunit4ClassRunner instead of JUnit3 runner...